# Caching a single file on Travis CI

Tags: docker, travis-ci

Inside my build on travis I need to first download a large `.tar.gz` file.

This `.tar.gz` never changes so it's a good idea cache it.

The `.tar.gz` it's downloaded inside my Dockerfile:

`RUN curl ftp://mycompanyftp.com/foo/bar/mylargefile.tar.gz -o /tmp/mylarge.tar.gz`

With that the docker container build with the file inside.

How can I cache this file?

**PS**: It's also possible to download the file on  `before_install` and use docker  `ADD` to put it inside the Docker container.

Comment: You can use the [standard TravisCI directory caching](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching) and download the file to e.g. `/tmp/cached/`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Travis CI cache a single file at a specified location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492750/travis-ci-cache-a-single-file-at-a-specified-location)

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible as long as you have this command in your `dockerfile`.

Instead, I suggest that you put this command in your `.travis.yml` file and download the file as part of the pre-build activities:

```
before_install: |
  if ! [ -f ./src/mylarge.tar.gz ]; then
    curl ftp://mycompanyftp.com/foo/bar/mylargefile.tar.gz -o ./src/mylarge.tar.gz;
  fi

install: |
  ./scripts/build.sh;

script: |
  ./scripts/test-integration.sh;

cache:
  directories:
    - $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/src/

after_success: |
  ./scripts/deploy.sh;
```

As you can see, the `before_install` section will download the file if it does not exist already. The `cache` section will tell Travis to keep the `./src/` directory and restore it at the beginning of your next build so it will not be downloaded for a second time.

In your `dockerfile`, what you want to do now instead of downloading is to just copy the local file into the container:

```
COPY ./src/mylargefile.tar.gz /tmp/mylargefile.tar.gz
```

You can read more about caching on Travis CI on their [docs page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/).