# Travis CI cache a single file at a specified location

Tags: caching, bundler, travis-ci

I am building a Ruby project on Travis CI and I use Gemfile ans Bundler to manage dependencies. My `.travis.yml` contains only one line about caching:

```
cache: bundler
```

And I rely on this in other places (Travis's default `install` command, cache directories, plus an extra `bundle clean` before uploading cache).

By default, `Gemfile.lock` is not cached. I want to cache it to make Bundler to skip dependency resolution and use the cached `Gemfile.lock`. I haven't found a valid solution for this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed the only comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35203169/5958455) and came up with an idea, but I think it's more a workaround than a solution.

Copy `Gemfile.lock` **from** `/tmp/cached` in `before_install` phase. The copy `Gemfile.lock` **to** `/tmp/cached` in `before_script` phase. This way it'll be cached by Travis CI and the cache will be used by Bundler.

I'm still looking for a real solution.

Answer (score 0):

AFAICS from [Travis' cacher implementation](https://github.com/travis-ci/casher/blob/bash/bin/casher),

- it will work if you specify a file name rather than a directory name under `cache: directories:`.<sup>1</sup>

With one caveat:

- Initially, when there's no cache (thus the file doesn't yet exist), the cache restore step will create an empty *directory* with this name.

  - You need to manually detect and delete this directory early in your build

Example `.travis.yml` (using an evvar for the file's path to avoid repeating it everywhere):

```yaml
env:
  global:
    - FILE=<path>
cache:
  directories:
    - $FILE
before_install:
  - if [[ -d $FILE ]]; then rm -rf "$FILE"; fi

# create and/or use the file
```

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>That's because they use `tar` to make and extract cache archives, and `tar` doesn't care if you pass a file or a directory to it</sub>